# How can I tell mapserver to ignore a filter that is set in a mapfile?

Tags: mapserver, filter, request

How can I tell mapserver to ignore a filter that is set in a mapfile?

I am displaying a wms layer with point features using mapserver. In one of the layers in my mapfile I have defined a filter similar to this:

```
FILTER          "mycolumn='%myvalue%'"
```

such that I can use [runtime substitution](http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html) in a mapserver request similar to this one:

```
http://someurl.com/mapserv?map=mymap.map&layer=mylayer&mode=map&myvalue=thisvalue
```

This works just fine.

However, sometimes I would like to display the entire dataset and thus forcing mapserver to ignore the filter.

Is it possible to deactivate the filter in a request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A working solution is similar to what @seruva19 suggested. The trick is to add a boolean value to the filter as an alternative to the previous filter:

```
FILTER    "(mycolumn='%myvalue%') or %allvars%"
```

where the validation forces the value to be `TRUE`

```
VALIDATION
  ...
  "allvals"    "^TRUE$"
END
```

and the default of `allvals` is set to `FALSE`

```
METADATA
    ...
    'default_allvals'   'FALSE'
END
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but this trick may work:

1. Add FILTER to validation block of the layer's description, like this:

   ```
   LAYER
   ...
       VALIDATION
         'FILTER' '.'
       END
   ...
   ```
2. When you want to show all of the data in your layer, add the following string to your URL request :

   ```
   &map.layer[mylayer]=FILTER+("[mycolumn]"+~*+".")
   ```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks a lot seruva19, your answer hinted in the right direction, helping me to get to the solution. I did not understand how yours works exactly...

Answer (score 0):

If I can help with this Answer. This two other solution.

Use a default value to void the filter clause.

```
VALIDATION
    myColumn'^[0-9]{1,2}$' 
    default_myColumn '0'
END
```

AND put the condition in the DATA

```
DATA "geometryColumn from (select * from MYTABLE where (('%myColumn%' = '0') or (myColumn='%myColumn%')) ) using srid 4326"
```

OR with a filter

Use a default value to void the filter clause.

```
VALIDATION
    myColumn'^[0-9]{1,2}$' 
    default_myColumn '0'
END
FILTER  ((('%myColumn%' = '0') or ([myColumn]='%myColumn%')))
```

Note than I expect an issue with single parenthesis with Oracle. I use double parenthesis to make it work correctly otherwise I got a full table scan. The debug show the Where clause with single parenthesis like that

```
WHERE   ( '0' = '0' ) OR ( myColumn= '0' )  AND …
```

with double parenthesis:

```
WHERE   (( '0' = '0' ) OR ( myColumn= '0' ))  AND …
```